# How can I download raw data from plotly bar charts?

Tags: download, graph

I'd like to download raw data from plotly COVID bar charts from the [Illinois dashboard](https://www.dph.illinois.gov/covid19/covid19-statistics) and the [Hopkins dashboard](https://coronavirus.jhu.edu/data/new-cases-50-states/illinois). There's no download button, but there must be a way to extract the data from the site.

In particular, I'd like to extract the list of Y-axis values. How can I do this? To clarify, for example in the chart below, I'd want to extract an array of about values that would look something like this `[130000 131000 132000 133333 ...]`.

[image: Example chart]

Comment: What web application are you using?

Comment: @Rubén [plotly](https://plotly.com/)

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plotly Plotly is a company, not a web application. Plotly.js is JavaScript library which are off-topic on this site.

Comment: @Rubén Fair enough, then the webapps are those which use Plotly+Dash, for example [Illinois' COVID dashboard](https://www.dph.illinois.gov/covid19/covid19-statistics), [Johns Hopkins' COVID dashboard](https://plotly.com/python/getting-started/), or any other webapp using this platform. See [the plotly docs](https://plotly.com/python/getting-started/), "Plotly enables visualizations ... served as part of pure Python-built web applications using Dash." These aren't desktop applications using the Python library, they're webapps.

Comment: The question isn't about how to use some Python library, it's how to use webapps that were created using this library.

Comment: In such case the question requires more focus.

Comment: @Rubén edited, let me know if this seems focused enough to you.

Comment: Since the question is about two different websites and that questions about technologies used by web apps are off-topic I suggest you to ask on [meta.se] if there is a site for question like this and/or directly take a look into [stats.se] and [datascience.se]. Check if they allow questions about web-scraping.

Comment: Or perhaps [law stack exchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/) when the answer ends up being FOIA the data. :/